# Inverse image of simply connected set under a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a non-constant polynomial. I want to show that all connected components of the inverse image of a simply connected $U\subset \mathbb{C}$ is simply connected again.

So let $V\subset f^{-1}(U)$ a connected component and let $\gamma$ be a loop based at $x_0\in V$. Then $f(\gamma)$ is a loop based at $f(x_0)$ and thus can be deformed to the constant loop. Let $H:I\times I\rightarrow U$ be this homotopy. Then if we take the inverse image of this $H$ and look at the component that lies in $V$, then this should give a homotopy of $\gamma$ to the constant loop. So $V$ is simply connected.

I am worried that this proof is not correct, since I am not using the fact that I have polynomial. Is this correct actually?

Comment: You might imagine the unit circle in $\mathbb R^2$ and project that to the $x$-axis.  Your argument would prove that the circle is simply connected.  Where does it break down?

Comment: @Gaffney I don't understand what you mean. I have a function which is globally defined and you are giving a function only defined on the circle.

Comment: But even in this scenario, I could write your same argument right?

Comment: @Gaffney Ah, I see what you mean now. In this case, the inverse image of the homotopy is not a loop.

Comment: @Gaffney Can you give me a hint on how to solve this?

Comment: I think you need to connect a couple of extra dots.  The pre-image of $H$ doesn't live in $V$.  I think you're think that you're trying to compose $H$ with the inverse of $f$, but this might not be continuous...  I'm not sure how to solve this.  I think your intuition is right that you'll need to use a property of polynomials (or at least that they're entire), and it'll probably matter also that it's complex.  It does seem though that your argument doesn't work, at least not without some additional justification.

Comment: I'd guess that a strategy for solving this would involve Cauchy's Integral Theorem.